# how to adjust dash line with width of screen

Tags: android

how to fixed dash line in UI full of width? in my screen dash line are not properly fully fit with width of screen see image  bellow.  I used manually `TextView` for dash if mobile width is small  is move to next line some dashes like below of if mobile width is thick is left some space form right side.

[image: My screenshot]

**My Code is as bellow:**

```
  <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/border5" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/test_button_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/iicon" >
            </ImageView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/test_button_text2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/test_button_image"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/test_button_image"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="Description"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/test_button_text23"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/test_button_text2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/test_button_text2"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="-------------------------------------------------"
                android:textColor="#000000" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/test_button_text2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/test_button_text23"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text=" "
                android:textColor="#000000" >
            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/border5" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/test_button_image20"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/iicon" >
            </ImageView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/test_button_text12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/test_button_image20"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/test_button_image20"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="Contains"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/test_button_text5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/test_button_text12"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/test_button_image20"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="---------------------------------------"
                android:textColor="#000000" >
            </TextView>

            <com.schoollunchapp.HorizontalListView
                android:id="@+id/listview2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/test_button_text5"
                android:background="#ffffff" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: how to fixed ------ line full of width??? auto fit with width of screen

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658772/android-vertical-line-xml

Comment: i just only want to show dash line with full width of screen noany space left from right side

Answer (score 1):

I tried to create doted lines but not sure its perfectly with your requirement.

**drawable/dotted.xml:**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line">

    <stroke
       android:color="#C7B299"
       android:dashWidth="10px"
       android:dashGap="10px" />
</shape>
```

**view.xml:**

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/dotted" />
```

For more understanding also refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11224795/1405983). Hope it helps.

Comment: Your parent view must be fill_parent. What are you getting using this code ?

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me :)

**drawable/dotted.xml**:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">

    <stroke
        android:dashWidth="10dp"
        android:dashGap="9dp"
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#757575" />
</shape>
```

**layout/my_activity.xml:**

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:src="@drawable/dotted" />
```